# WSO2 MB 3.0.0 Startup Error : Wait until Qpid server starts on port 5672

Tags: wso2, qpid, wso2-message-broker

I just downloaded the WSO2 MB 3.0.0. And when I trying to start server I'm getting following error.

```
[2016-04-28 14:43:21,986] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent} -  Wait until Qpid server starts on port 5672
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:198)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
    at org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent.startAMQPServer(QpidServiceComponent.java:429)
    at org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent.startAndesBroker(QpidServiceComponent.java:378)
    at org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent.activate(QpidServiceComponent.java:149)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
```

Please help me fix this.

Comment: check if you have 5672  port in use.

Comment: I checked. Port is open to use.

Comment: are you getting this on a fresh pack? did you did any config changes?

Comment: Yes Thusitha, this is a fresh MB. Didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above error is showing in startup url printer due as qpid server not binding with port 5672 at the time startup url printer checks for the qpid server. However after few minutes (usually 1 - 2 minutes) WSO2MB will start normally with qpid server. So you don't worry about it in first place.

Anyway I have experienced the same issue on the systems where firewall is enabled. So you should check after disabling firewall in first place. If it is not happening after disabling the firewall, then try to configure firewall rules appropriately before enabling it.

Thanks

Comment: This answer was correct for me too, although it seemed to take closer to twenty minutes for the error to go away..

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when I had active some VPN connection in the background (did not use it for this particular case though). I suppose that WSO2 tried to connect to incorrect IP address instead of localhost. Temporarily disconnecting VPN solved this issue.

Comment: Some VPN connection was messing with the WSO2 API manager.

Comment: First time using WS02 and you solution helped to fix this. but WS02 is starting and starting and statring and never ending :(

Answer (score 1):

Go to file repository/conf/broker.xml and change value of element transports/amqp/localhost from 0.0.0.0 to localhost.